# Is there any difference between `inline constexpr bool` and `concept`

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

```
template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_int_v1 = std::is_same_v<T, int>;

template<typename T>
concept is_int_v2 = std::is_same_v<T, int>;
```

In this code block whats the difference between the `inline constexpr bool` format and the `concept` format.
Is one better over the other or are they equivalent?

Comment: They have nothing in common except that both may be used as expressions in the form `is_int_vX<T>` where `T` is a type to evaluate to a `bool`. So the questions seems a bit weird.

Comment: @user17732522 I understand both evaluate to true/false, hence my question.
so if i want something like this what method is preferable?

Comment: @tejas The second does no evaluate to true/false. It is a ***concept***.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many differences. Variables are *variables*; even if they are `inline constexpr`, they are still variables. They represent objects and you can take their addresses.

A `concept` is not a variable at all. You cannot take its address or do anything of the kind with it. `concept`s get special grammatical rules like `void func(ConceptName auto x);` that variables do not.

Variables can be templates and get to undergo template specialization. `concept`s don't get to be specialized; this is deliberate. A specific concept name is associated with exactly one constraint expression no matter what template arguments are given to it.

But the most important difference is that `concept`s get to follow [special subsumption rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59953061/734069) during instantiation.

When you attempt to instantiate a template that is constrained, C++ goes through a number of steps to determine which of the matching templates is the "most constrained" version that could be applied. The most constrained form is given greater weight during the resolution of which template to instantiate.

`std::signed_integral<T>` is defined in terms of `std::integral<T>`.

```
template<class T>
  concept signed_­integral = integral<T> && is_signed_v<T>;
```

This means that, if some type `T` satisfies `signed_integral`, then it necessarily satisfies `integral`. If you have two versions of the same template, one constrained with `integral` and one with `signed_integral`, then passing `unsigned int` will necessarily instantiate the first.

`int` satisfies both concepts. But since the compiler knows that `signed_integral` contains `integral`, it is considered "more constrained". And therefore, that template is given priority if a type fulfills both.

That *only happens* if you use a `concept`. If these were just `inline constexpr` variables, then attempting to use `int` would get a compile error since both constraints are given equal weight.

`inline constexpr` variables are essentially black boxes to the constraint system. `concept`s are *part of* the constraint system.