# Is a constexpr bool an atomic constraint?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Look at this code ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7ovjnGqrs)):

```
template <typename TYPE>
constexpr bool c1 = TYPE::c1;

template <typename TYPE>
constexpr bool c2 = TYPE::c2;

template <typename TYPE>
requires c1<TYPE>
struct Foo {};

template <typename TYPE>
requires c1<TYPE> && c2<TYPE>
struct Foo<TYPE> {};
```

This code compiles with MSVC, but not with gcc/clang (note: if you change `constexpr bool` to `concept`, the code compiles).

Does the partial specialization in the example have a more specialized constraint than the primary template? I'm trying to figure out whether `c1<TYPE>` and `c2<TYPE>` are atomic constraints or not.

Based on [temp.constr.normal](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.normal), I would have expected that a form of `E1 && E2` is always splitted into two parts, so `c1<TYPE>` should be atomic, and the code should compile. Even, [temp.constr.atomic/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#constr.atomic-1) has a note "Atomic constraints are formed by constraint normalization. E is never a logical and expression nor a logical or expression". As `c1<TYPE> && c2<TYPE>` is logical and expression, it should not be atomic based on this note.

But on the other hand, temp.constr.normal has an explicit rule about `concept`s. This rules shouldn't be necessary to make a `concept` atomic, because if `E1 && E2` is always splitted into two parts, they would become atomic anyway.

Which compiler is correct? If gcc/clang, where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: when composing constraints, concepts allow for subsumption, while `constexpr bool` don't. [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952704/c20-concepts-which-template-specialization-gets-chosen-when-the-template-arg/59953061#59953061)

Comment: I found a related blog post: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2020/05/07/ordering-by-constraints/

Comment: I believe this is because only named constraints are considered equivalent when comparing constraints. So the partial specialization isn't considered a specialization of `Foo` because the constraints can never match. You only need to change `c1` to be a `concept` and it works